# Removing Decimals From Line Chart Axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google line chart I'm using and in many cases the numbers on the axis represent decimals point. Obviously since my data represents people it makes no sense to show the axis in decimal points. I would like for them to rounded up to whole numbers. So far I've been toiling with the `format` option in the `xAxis` like so.

```
  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Dogs',
      format: 'long'
    }
  };
```

However, the points on the xAxis are represented as decimals. The jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t17Lj6h9/2/). What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: How about format: number, fractionDigits: 0 ?

Comment: simply use `format:'#'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set custom format specifiers such as:

- `#` (Digit placeholder)
- `0` (Zero placeholder)

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

    data.addRows([
      [0, 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Dogs',
            format: '#'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Another option is to specify `hAxis.ticks`:

> Replaces the automatically generated X-axis ticks with the specified
>   array.

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

    data.addRows([
      [0, 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Dogs',
            //format: '#'
            ticks: [-1,0,1]
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```